# Feature Request: Add a "My Questions" button at top on stack

Tags: discussion, feature-request, navigation

I want to have a quick look of the questions I asked on stack. Currently for that I have to go to my profile, find the required stack community and then the question.

Is it possible to have a "My Questions" tab (just like "Ask Question", "Answers" etc tabs) which shows my question history for all of my stack communities?

Comment: For me, http://stackexchange.com/users/251740/rory-alsop?tab=activity gives me a timeline of my activity, including answers and questions

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That is possible of course, but hardly useful to a lot of users. I hardly ever ask questions on my main site, Stack Overflow.

I also wonder if this would be useful to users asking questions more often. It can be useful to quickly find the questions you have asked, but I guess generally you don't search for more than one question. A quick peek in your notifications will most certainly yield the activity on the last questions you have asked, and the user profile is not fair away.

Given the lack of space I would say this feature is not useful enough to add it there.

Comment: I would argue that a "My Answers" would be more helpful to most people.